# Trimming Phonegap when not using any native features, is it possible?

Tags: iphone, cordova, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a simple lightweight webbapp which I intend to wrap as a Phonegap app for iPhone and possibly Android.

The thing is, I don't actually use ANY of the native features available via Phonegap, such as the camera or GPS. Do you know any ways for me to trim Phonegap so that I can have an app which is as light-weight and fast as possible?

For example, can I trim or even leave out phonegap.js? Any objecive-c code or resources that can be dropped?

Alternatively, does anyone know of some other bare bones webview wrapper which is lighter than Phonegap to begin with?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You likely can leave out phonegap.js, or at least substantially trim it.

PhoneGap provides two distinct sets of capabilities:

1. Provide a set of JavaScript APIs to access native capabilities
2. Wrap a set of HTML assets into a native application

For Android, #2 is completely implemented in phonegap.jar. #1 requires the addition of phonegap.js. Thus if you don't need the APIs, you don't need phonegap.js. I haven't tested on IOS, but would expect it to be a similar story.

Comment: It is similar on iOS. Do however consider that phonegap.js is lightweight and trimming it without trimming its native couterpart won't bring any major improvement. On the native side, you could also disable the unneeded plugins both on iOS and Android.